# coordination.k8s.io api in GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-apiserver

I'm trying the leader-election code example provided with the go client ([here](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/tree/master/examples/leader-election)) in a GKE cluster v1.13.7.

That requires a resource of type `Lease` of groupVersion `coordination.k8s.io/v1` but there isn't. I know that Lease has been promoted to v1 in k8s 1.14 (not yet available with gke), but I expected to find the v1beta1 version.

Try with

```
kubectl proxy
curl -X GET localhost:8001/apis/coordination.k8s.io
```

and I get 
`404 page not found`

Answer (score 0):

Although the feature is v1 in 1.14, GKE has not incorporated this feature yet.
Since GKE is a fully managed product, the eng team decide which features to incorporate I to the GKE offering.

I recommend opening a feature request through the Google Public Issue Tracker and provide your use case for the feature to have integrated in future releases